# Bizarre error message in VC12 when attempting to create pool allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am attempting to create a simple pool allocator that can work with containers like list and map.  First, I have the class `free_list` which inherits from the node type that is used by the container and uses a specialized forward linked list (with all its memory already allocated--allocation occurs when the first item is allocated by the allocator) to give and take back memory requested in the allocator's `allocate` and `deallocate` functions.  Then I have the class `pool_alloc` which implements the allocator itself and returns and accepts in its allocation and deallocation functions `free_list<T>` object types.

The problem child is this statement: `m_next->give_back(ptr);` under `pool_alloc::deallocate`, which returns VC12 error C2664: It says I cannot convert from type '`free_list<T>*`' to type '`free_list<free_list<T>>*`'.

I do not understand why `free_list<T>::give_back` expects type `free_list<free_list<T>>*` when one would expect it to expect `free_list<T>*`.

Is there any way to fix this?

The full source code is below:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
class free_list : public T {
public:
    free_list* init(std::size_t num_elements) {

        m_next = this;
        free_list* temp = m_next + 1;

        free_list* runner = m_next;
        for (std::size_t s = 1; s < num_elements; ++s) {
            runner->m_next = temp;
            runner = temp;
            temp = runner + 1;
        }
        runner->m_next = nullptr;

        return m_next;
    }

    free_list* obtain() {
        free_list* head = m_next;
        m_next = m_next->m_next;
        return head;
    }

    void give_back(free_list* ptr) {
        ptr->m_next = m_next;
        m_next = ptr;
    }

    free_list* m_next;

};

template<class T>
class pool_alloc {
    typedef pool_alloc<T> myt;

public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef free_list<T> value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef free_list<T>* pointer;
    typedef const free_list<T>* const_pointer;

    template<class U>
    struct rebind {
        typedef pool_alloc<U> other;
    };

    pool_alloc() : data(nullptr), m_next(nullptr), capacity(4096), allocated(0) {}
    pool_alloc(std::size_t capacity) : data(nullptr), m_next(nullptr), capacity(capacity), allocated(0) {}

    T* address(reference ref) {
        return &ref;
    }

    const T* address(const_reference ref) const {
        return &ref;
    }

    std::size_t max_size() const {
        return capacity;
    }

    pointer allocate(std::size_t) {
        if (allocated >= capacity) throw(std::bad_alloc());
        if (allocated == 0) {
            data = (void*) new char[capacity * sizeof(free_list<T>)];
            m_next = static_cast<free_list<value_type>*>(data);
            m_next->init(capacity);
        }
        return m_next->obtain();
    }

    void deallocate(pointer ptr, std::size_t) {
        m_next->give_back(ptr);
        --allocated;
        if (allocated == 0) {
            delete[](char*)(data);
            data = nullptr;
            m_next = nullptr;
        }
    }

    template<class T, class... Args>
    void construct(T* ptr, Args&&... args) {
        ::new ((void*) ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <class T>
    void destroy(T* ptr) {
        ptr->~T();
    }

    bool operator==(const myt& other) {
        return (char)(data) == (char)(other.data);
    }

    bool operator!=(const myt& other) {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

private:

    void* data;
    free_list<value_type>* m_next;
    std::size_t capacity;
    std::size_t allocated;

};
```

Comment: I've compiled your code with VS 2012 right now and I don't get that error... :-S

Comment: The error probably comes from the code that *uses* this code, which he didn't include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that weird: you've defined `value_type` (incorrectly) to be `free_list<T>` instead of `T`, so `m_next` has type `free_list<free_list<T>>`. `pointer` and `const_pointer` have the same issue.

Other issues:

- `pool_alloc` doesn't have proper copy/move/assignment operators defined.
- `pool_alloc` doesn't have a templated constructor that accepts `const pool_alloc<U>&`, so you won't be able to initialize
- `pool_alloc::allocate` will do horrible things if anyone ever tries to make a `std::vector<T, pool_alloc<T>>`. You should probably either assert that the argument is 1 or fallback to `::operator new(n * sizeof(T))` if the argument is greater than 1.
- `operator==` and `operator!=` should probably be `const`.
- `construct` and `destroy` could also be `const`, or even `static`.
- It's not necessary to keep both `data` and `m_next`, since they're different typed aliases for the same value - just cast `m_next` to `void*` whenever you need `data`.
- Dumping the memory chunk in `deallocate` instead of in `~pool_alloc` could have pathological performance for e.g `std::stack<T, std::list<T, pool_alloc<T>>`.
- The "list" initialization in `free_list<T>::init` is pointing each node's `m_next` pointer at itself instead of building a list. Should be:

  ```
  void init(std::size_t num_elements) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num_elements - 1; ++i) {
        this[i]->m_next = &this[i + 1];
    }
    this[num_elements - 1]->m_next = nullptr;
  }
  ```